# HBase error : Memstore size is xxxxxx

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ycsb

Hi guys I am trying to deal with the Hbase problem form long time.I downloaded open source HBase and its running in distributed mode.I am trying to do benchmarking using YCSB tool.When I try to give recordcount and operationcount more than 10,000 all my region servers fails saying following error message.What could be the reason.Did anybody knows about it??

```
        2016-06-17 05:42:05,690 ERROR [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c:16020-2] regionserver.HRegion: Memstore size is 3128720
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,690 ERROR [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c:16020-0] regionserver.HRegion: Memstore size is 2997680
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,691 INFO  [StoreCloserThread-usertable2,user1149,1466144447147.c05f26226518c55e7c044d1a0b0ddfda.-1] regionserver.HStore: Closed cf
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,691 INFO  [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c:16020-2] regionserver.HRegion: Closed usertable2,user2049,1466144447147.af882a98492dbbef2fd8fefdd2677a98.
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,691 INFO  [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c:16020-0] regionserver.HRegion: Closed usertable2,user7749,1466144447147.76fc8f821453fda0cd30f8ebf6c6355a.
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,691 ERROR [RS_CLOSE_REGIONc:16020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Memstore size is 2972200
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,693 INFO  [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c-71:16020-1] regionserver.HRegion: Closed usertable2,user1149,1466144447147.c05f26226518c55e7c044d1a0b0ddfda.
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,693 INFO  [StoreCloserThread-usertable1,user3339,1466019203359.e58eabbbb681e0dbede57981054b4282.-1] regionserver.HStore: Closed cf
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,693 INFO  [StoreCloserThread-usertable1,user9099,1466019203359.4f8669a820bbdecb866e834e27850ac5.-1] regionserver.HStore: Closed cf
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,693 INFO  [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c:16020-2] regionserver.HRegion: Closed usertable1,user3339,1466019203359.e58eabbbb681e0dbede57981054b4282.
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,693 INFO  [RS_CLOSE_REGION-c:16020-0] regionserver.HRegion: Closed usertable1,user9099,1466019203359.4f8669a820bbdecb866e834e27850ac5.
    2016-06-17 05:42:05,693 INFO  [StoreFileCloserThread-cf-1] 
ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Region server exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: HRegionServer Aborted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:126)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:2667)
```

Comment: i'm afraid that's not the useful log. The error message means that when you close a region while the memstore still have data. maybe you can provide more details.

Comment: I solved this issue.I changed the heap size for region servers also memstore size is tuned.

Comment: Hi Ankita, Can you comment the commands you used to do this in the answer?